# Problem with ForeignKey, Django migrations

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, primary-key, migrate

When I tried to migrate my project to a different version I faced this error:

> ProgrammingError: ERROR:  the id column specified in the foreign key constraint does not exist.

**UPDATE: This is the full log**: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 525, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 122, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 750, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model, new_field, "_fk_%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s"))
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/MyProjects/forest-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

But I don't have an id column in my model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from renter.models import RefAbstract, Renter
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from textwrap import shorten
 
    
class Unitt(RefAbstract):
   ....//some classes
class Task(RefAbstract):
    class Meta(RefAbstract.Meta):
        verbose_name = 'task'
        verbose_name_plural = 'tasks'

class Spatial(models.Model):
    codeq = models.IntegerField('no',help_text='no') 
    code = models.PositiveIntegerField('cutare',primary_key=True,help_text='cutare')//unique column
    codeV = models.IntegerField('novi',help_text='novi') 
    renter = models.ForeignKey(Renter, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='renter')
    geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True, verbose_name='geometry')
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'cutarea'
        verbose_name_plural = 'cutarea'


class LScharacteristic(models.Model):
    codels = models.ForeignKey(Spatial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name = 'cutarea')// Foreign Key
    tract = models.CharField('tract',max_length = 80, help_text='tract') 
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task,  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='task')
    totalarea = models.PositiveIntegerField('totarea',help_text = 'totarea')
    explarea = models.PositiveIntegerField('exarea',help_text = 'exarea')
    protecttype = models.CharField('category',max_length = 50, help_text = 'category')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'characteristic'
        verbose_name_plural = 'characteristics'

class PlannedUsing(models.Model):
    codels = models.ForeignKey(Spatial, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name = 'cutarea') // Foreign Key   
    codeq = models.IntegerField(help_text='number')
    cutareaShape = models.ForeignKey(CutareaShape, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='form')
    cuttype = models.ForeignKey(CutareaType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='type1')
    managetype = models.ForeignKey(ManageType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='type2')
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unitt, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='unit')
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='sort')
    assortment = models.ForeignKey(Assortment, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='assort')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'planus'
        verbose_name_plural = 'planuss'
```

What is the id column and why does it exist if I never defined it?
How I can to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your ForeignKey fields do not point explicitly to the field that you have marked as primary (`Spatial.code`).
By marking `Spatial.code` as primary you prevent Django from creating the id field. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) But if you point a ForeignKey to just a model it will try to link to the id field of that model.
To fix this you can add to your ForeignKey field the parameter: `to_field='code'` and add `unique=True` to `Spatial.code`.[See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.etat
```

or

```
def __int__(self):
```

For specif what do you return on your django model.
like this:

```
tests= models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Test")
class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tests"
        ordering = ['tests']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tests
```

Comment: It is didn't work for me. i use this constriction, but error is saved.